# Use query to populate an extend in KQL?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a JSON property bag being received as an update to configuration. I would like to retrieve the existing latest property bag from the table, manipulate it to remove the keys that are being updated using the bag_remove_keys and bag_merge operators.

This is being used in an update policy, so I have the new property bag in an extend from the input data, I need to perform a new extend to retrieve the current latest property set existing in the table.

Something similar to the below:

```
            rawhsimessages 
            //Get @RecType
            | extend ParsedMessage = parse_json(Message)
            | extend Objects = ParsedMessage["ExportedConfig"]["Objects"]
            | parse Objects with "[" Objects "]"
            | extend Properties = parse_json(Objects)
            | extend RecType =  Properties["@RecType"] 
            | where RecType == "CHANGE"
            | extend latestconfig = XXXX(GeoSCADAConfigurationTest | where Id == Properties["Id"] | summarize arg_max(ConfigTime, Properties)
            | project-away Message, ParsedMessage, Objects
```

Can I replace the XXXX with anything that will allow me to do this?

If not, is there a better approach I can take?

Comment: Hi James, it seems that you trying to make update-policy to depend on the data that exists in another table (T1). If the table T1 is the same table that update policy is updating - the scenario may not work as you expect due to the fact that the system can have many concurrent ingestions running, and there is a clear race of what each update policy sees as latest value in the table T1.
Also, please provide any input data sample (using datatable() literal - and demonstrate what exactly is the logic you would like to achieve).

Comment: Thanks, Alexander, I have made another post that is a bit more specific to my problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66500704/kql-join-on-max-value