# KQL Join on max value

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to join on a table to return the MAX value from that right-hand table. I have tried to mock it up using 'datatable' but have failed miserably :(. I'll try and describe with words.

```
T1 = datatable(ID:int, Properties:string, ConfigTime:datetime) [1,'a,b,c','2021-03-04 00:00:00']

T2 = datatable(ID:int, Properties:string, ConfigTime:datetime) [2,'a,b,c','2021-03-02 00:00:00', 3,'a,b','2021-03-01 00:00:00', 4,'c','2021-03-20 00:00:00']
```

I'm using this as an update policy on T2, which has a source of T1. So I want to select the rows from T1 and then join the rows from T2 that have the highest timestamp. My first attempt was below:

```
T1 | join kind=inner T2 on Id
   | summarize arg_max(ConfigTime1, Id, Properties, Properties1, ConfigTime) by Id
   | project Id, Properties, ConfigTime
```

In my actual update policy, I merge the properties from T1 and T2 then write to  T2, but for simplicity, I've left that for now.

Currently, I'm not getting any output in my T2 from the update policy. Any guidance on another way I should be doing this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to push the arg_max calculation into the T2 side of the join, something like this:

```
T1 
| join kind=inner (
   T2 
   | summarize arg_max(ConfigTime1, Id, Properties, Properties1, ConfigTime) by Id
   | project Id, Properties, ConfigTime
) on Id
```

Note that to ensure acceptable performance you want to limit the timeframe for the arg_max search, so you should consider a time based filter before the arg_max.

Comment: Hi Avnera, Yes, T2 is supposed to contain the most recent properties for a given Id, the difficulty i have is that T1 will receive partial proeprty bags for each Id as they change, The update policy for T2 needs to receive the update from T1 and get the most recent property bag from T2 to merge the properties from T1, making a combined, updated proeprty bag which can then be written to T2. I'm not sure materialised view would work if the property entries in T2 were not all complete property sets i.e some rows being partial properties.

Comment: I see. why don't apply the arg_max only on the T2 only and then join? i.e. :
 T1 | join kind=inner (T2 | summarize arg_max(ConfigTime1, Id, Properties, Properties1, ConfigTime) by Id
   | project Id, Properties, ConfigTime) on Id

Note that to ensure acceptable performance you want to limit the timeframe for the arg_max search, so you should consider a time based filter before the arg_max

Comment: Thank you so much Avnera, you have been such a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a union

```
let T1 = datatable(ID:int, Properties:string, ConfigTime:datetime) [
    1,'a,b,c','2021-03-04 00:00:00'
];
let T2 = datatable(ID:int, Properties:string, ConfigTime:datetime) [
    2,'a,b,c','2021-03-02 00:00:00', 
    3,'a,b','2021-03-01 00:00:00', 
    4,'c','2021-03-20 00:00:00'
];
```

Here is an example using a variable with summarize max:

```
let Latest = toscalar(T2 | summarize max(ConfigTime));
T1
| union (T2 | where ConfigTime == Latest)
```

The result will keep the entries from T1 and only the latest entries from T2.

[image: results output]

If this doesn't reflect your expected results please show your expected output.

Comment: Hi, as its an update policy for a table, eventually writing a single row, I think I need a join so that all the columns are kept on a single row, and I can 'project' the columns i need in the final output.

An example output would be ID, Properties, ConfigTime, where properties are a merged bag of the most recent properties from T2, updated with the partial properties from T1.

Comment: Sorry but it's a little hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. A picture says a thousand words. Can you update your question with your immediate expected results and desired final results? If you have Excel you can easily paste in mock results